# How to implement this type of GridView in Android?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I implemented a GridView like below:

[image]

But when I rotate the phone this is what happens:

[image]

I want the images stay the way they are in Portrait mode. I don't want spacing between views.

**Grid view:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:columnWidth="170dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Grid Item:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I'm re-sizing image in the adapter like below:

```
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
ImageItem item = data.get(position);
holder.image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(item.getImage(), 180, 200, true));
```

I also want the images to re-size properly without any blurring, etc.

Comment: Do you want items with no space in portrait mode??

Comment: android:layout_height="200dp" is causing the problem, better you create a new layout for your Landscape mode

Comment: Probably, the android:columnWidth attribute being fixed is causing the issue. Also, your android:stretchMode is set to this columnWidth.

Comment: @Raghunandan I want the items to have no space vertically or horizontally both in Portrait and Landscape mode.

Comment: @Someone use this http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-autofit-grid.html with recyclerview. No paddings no decoration for items should give you want you want

Comment: @Someone also it is better have some gap between items. equal gaps so that it looks nice

Answer (score 0):

You have given `android:columnWidth="170dp"` and in **griditem.xml** you have given fixed height,That why this thing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

use following example for auto adjustment of gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"/>

</FrameLayout>
```